# Load RabbitMQ config at startup

Tags: rabbitmq

How do I load a RabbitMQ config at startup to confirm that broker objects (queues, exchanges, bindings, users, virtual hosts, permissions and parameters) are created?

According to the RabbitMQ documentation, it can be done via `load_definitions` http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#load-definitions

But I can't figure out how to use it. Would someone mind sharing an example of how this works? I can't find any examples online.

Answer (score 20):

There's two bits that the documentation leaves to be desired that were stumbling blocks for me.

**Generating the definitions file**

I found the easiest way to do that is to configure one RabbitMQ server how you like it and then...

1. Go to the management web interface
2. Look at the bottom of the Overview tab/page for the "Import / export definitions" heading
3. Click the "Download broker definitions" button in that section

**Configuring RabbitMQ to look for a definitions file at startup**

1. Put the definitions file somewhere on the filesystem that it can be read by the user that your rabbitmq daemon will be running as.
2. Include a block like this in the configuration file:

   `{rabbitmq_management, [
   {listener, [...]},
   {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"} ]},`

Upon startup, those definitions should get loaded. Any errors loading them should be apparent in the logs.

Comment: If you have `rabbitmqadmin` installed you can also do `./rabbitmqadmin export definitions.json` to export your definitions

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think it would be still useful to include example `definitions.json` file in your answer, for those who install RabbitMQ on server and cannot use web interface.

Comment: This uses the old configuration format, which is incompatible with things that the docker image for 3.7 does. Do you know the corresponding configuration in the new format?

Comment: The actual [config](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example) is a file full of settings. When you mentioned add a block as shown above, should I delete all other settings and add this one or just append the given settings to the linked files?

Comment: @Vino @Jan-hudec the new style would be `management.load_definitions = /path/to/definitions/file.json` but the old style should still work. For more information you can go [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#load-definitions)