# RabbitMQ loading users from property file

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414364/loading-rabbitmq-config-at-startup) as inspiration, I'm attempting to load rabbitMQ configuration from file on initial start-up, since this will be ran in a docker container.

Using the Docker RabbitMQ image, I'm starting with the following command:

```
docker run -d -h rabbit-host --name rabbit-queue -v /opt/docker/rabbit/mnesia:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia -v /opt/docker/rabbit/config:/etc/rabbitmq -v /opt/docker/log/rabbit:/var/lib/rabbitmq/log -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -e RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=/var/lib/rabbitmq/log rabbitmq:3.5-management
```

There are two files located at /opt/docker/rabbit/config that are attached to the docker window.

**rabbitmq.config**

```js
[
        {rabbitmq_management, [
                {load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json"}
                ]
        }
].
```

**definitions.json** (Exported from a known good configuration's admin console)

```js
{"rabbit_version": "3.5.0",
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "g",
      "password_hash": "xxx",
      "tags": "administrator"
    },
    {
      "name": "a",
      "password_hash": "xxx=",
      "tags": "administrator"
    },
    {
      "name": "t",
      "password_hash": "xxx=",
      "tags": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "password_hash": "xxx=",
      "tags": "administrator"
    },
    {
      "name": "j",
      "password_hash": "\/xxx\/Wet8=",
      "tags": "administrator"
    },
    {
      "name": "g",
      "password_hash": "xxx+IJRpR3Bh4=",
      "tags": "administrator"
    },
    {
      "name": "j",
      "password_hash": "0Qlvj0o+xxx+xxx=",
      "tags": "administrator"
    }
  ],
  "vhosts": [
    {
      "name": "\/"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    {
      "user": "guest",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    },
    {
      "user": "j",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    },
    {
      "user": "a",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    },
    {
      "user": "g",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    },
    {
      "user": "t",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    },
    {
      "user": "j",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    },
    {
      "user": "b",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": [

  ],
  "policies": [

  ],
  "queues": [
    {
      "name": "auditLogQueue",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "durable": true,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "arguments": {

      }
    },
    {
      "name": "auditlog.gw.local",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "durable": true,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "arguments": {

      }
    }
  ],
  "exchanges": [
    {
      "name": "spring-boot-exchange",
      "vhost": "\/",
      "type": "topic",
      "durable": true,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "internal": false,
      "arguments": {

      }
    }
  ],
  "bindings": [

  ]
}
```

Here's what I see on startup:

```js
              RabbitMQ 3.5.0. Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: tty
  ######  ##        /var/lib/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@rabbit-host-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...
=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:52 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.5.0 on Erlang 17.4
Copyright (C) 2007-2014 GoPivotal, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:52 ===
node           : rabbit@rabbit-host
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash    : jbD/nyBuT4vYLbfKO4tc3g==
log            : tty
sasl log       : /var/lib/rabbitmq/log/rabbit@rabbit-host-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbit-host

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:54 ===
Limiting to approx 524188 file handles (471767 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:54 ===
    application: mnesia
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:54 ===
Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:55 ===
Memory limit set to 3191MB of 7978MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:57 ===
Disk free limit set to 50MB

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
Adding vhost '/'

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
Creating user 'guest'

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
Setting user tags for user 'guest' to [administrator]

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
Setting permissions for 'guest' in '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=WARNING REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
msg_store_persistent: rebuilding indices from scratch

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672
 completed with 0 plugins.

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:58 ===
Server startup complete; 0 plugins started.
```

At the very least, Rabbit is attempting to read the rabbit.config, as it will throw an error if it's not. But, rabbit isn't picking up the definitions.json, and goes on to create the standard 'guest' user. Any suggestions to what the problem is? Or, any alternatives to loading users and queue names on startup?

Comment: I can see that you have management plugin enabled ( `-p 15672:15672 ` ).  So to take things off the table you can try to send your definitions using `curl` from the host ( or the docker ).

Comment: Also try to replace `password_hash` with `password` and load password in plain text

Comment: It is strange that you get this in the logs:

`=INFO REPORT==== 15-Apr-2015::22:01:54 ===
    application: mnesia
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary`

Comment: I appreciate both of your's help. The problem ended up being that I was mounting a directory as part of the docker image, and it was overwriting configuration files that the Dockerfile was writing to the container to that same directory (/etc/rabbitmq).

And, for what it's worth, it still appears that I got the "application: mnesia exited: stopped type: temporary" INFO REPORT.

Comment: @Andrew Could you please explain in more detail about what you did fix this? I am having the same issue as well. In my `Dockerfile`, I am `ADD`ing `rabbitmq.config` to `/etc/rabbitmq/`. But my definitions are not picked up.